# Need jQuery.load() to return HTML but server-side handler method only accepts POST method?

Tags: jquery

What do you do if you call the `load` method like so:

```
$('#result').load('/return_result');
```

and you get a server error that says

```
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

`load()` seems perfect for what I want to do - return HTML from the server and put it into the `#result` element.

Answer (score 1):

use post instead :)

```
$.post('/return_result', function(data){
    $('#result').empty().html(data);
});
```

Comment: Just curious.. How do you know `/return_result` uses POST?

Comment: it's an assumption based on there request not accepting get.  usually it's one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

load by defaults use the `HTTP` method as `GET`. Looks like the url `/return_result` doesnot accept `GET`. If it is your service make sure it supports `GET`. or use `.ajax()` method of jQuery to set the `type` to what ever method it supports.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `$.ajax()` method instead, as you can control what HTTP verb it will use.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/return_result",
   success: function(msg){
      alert( "response: " + msg );
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of the `.load()` method must be some representation of HTML code, whether it be a div, or an entire page.  It seems as if `'/return_result'` doesn't meet those requirements. If I am wrong, and the element does contain HTML, try using the jQuery `$('#div').empty()` and `$('#div').appendTo('destination')` methods.

Answer (score 0):

If your server only supports POST, then Just add a dummy data string to be posted like this,

```
$('#result').load('/return_result', {test: 10});
```

Then the method will switch to using POST method. But this may not be the most elegant solution.